# Display and Print RDL report without reportViewer control in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I need to display and Print the Rdl reports which are in the Report Server

Answer (score 0):

Use the webservices provided at the http://myserver/ReportServer endpoint.  They are fairly easy to consume and documented well on the web.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx